# How to share the link of a web intelligence document to others

Tags: webi

I've opened a  SAP (BO) Webi riport which is interesting for some of us.

Therefore I wanted to share the link of the specific Webi riport in outlook, so we could all talk about the same document.

In the webrowser url I only see the same url, so I cannot share that link.

What I've found that in the html there is a Iframe which contains the right link.

The problem is that it contains my token which expires in 15 minutes, therefore the link won't last.

What could be the solution how can i share url, for specific report to my collegues ?

[https://vir.nisz.hu/BOE/portal/2104011024/AnalyticalReporting/webiNG/app/index.html#WEBI/opendoc/1740314/?rwsrooturl=https%3A%2F%2Fvir2.nisz.hu%2Fbiprws⟨=hu&pvl=hu_HU&theme=sap_belize&wingMode=OpenDocument&token=dmlycHJvZC5uaXN6Lmh1OjY0MDBAezMmMj0xNzQyODI0LFUzJjJ2PXZpcnByb2Qubmlzei5odTo2NDAwLFVQJjY2PTQwLFUzJjY4PXNlY0VudGVycHJpc2U6Q3plaXRuZXJBWkBrb3BkYXQubG9jYWwsVVAmUzk9MjA4NDgsVTMmcWU9MTAwLFUzJnZ6PVNta0l0c2t0R0oycE1XaVBiRmJBXzBqbUp5QWdZZzdpN1BscGR4MnJOcnUyaGJEOWpscy5UX1NzWi51eDlDSUksVVB9&isOpenDocLink=true](https://vir.nisz.hu/BOE/portal/2104011024/AnalyticalReporting/webiNG/app/index.html#WEBI/opendoc/1740314/?rwsrooturl=https%3A%2F%2Fvir2.nisz.hu%2Fbiprws%E2%9F%A8=hu&pvl=hu_HU&theme=sap_belize&wingMode=OpenDocument&token=dmlycHJvZC5uaXN6Lmh1OjY0MDBAezMmMj0xNzQyODI0LFUzJjJ2PXZpcnByb2Qubmlzei5odTo2NDAwLFVQJjY2PTQwLFUzJjY4PXNlY0VudGVycHJpc2U6Q3plaXRuZXJBWkBrb3BkYXQubG9jYWwsVVAmUzk9MjA4NDgsVTMmcWU9MTAwLFUzJnZ6PVNta0l0c2t0R0oycE1XaVBiRmJBXzBqbUp5QWdZZzdpN1BscGR4MnJOcnUyaGJEOWpscy5UX1NzWi51eDlDSUksVVB9&isOpenDocLink=true)

Thanks